# Why is my Javascript not working to display the tab in HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got the javascript function that is supposed to create a new tab and add it in HTML when you click on the "+" tab. Then, this new tab is displayed However, it isn't being displayed with my css. I've scanned through my code many times, and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am new to HTML/CSS/Javascript, and come from a Java background, if that helps any.

```js
function addTab() {

  //create a new div element
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");

  //create the id and add tab content class
  newDiv.setAttribute("id", "newtab") //sets id name for div
  newDiv.className = "tabcontent"; //sets class for div

  //give tab some text
  const tabContent = document.createTextNode("Testing the add tab button!");
  newDiv.appendChild(tabContent);

  //create the tab
  var btn = document.createElement("button"); //creates button
  btn.className = "tablinks"; //sets class for button

  //give onclick event to button
  var event = Event;
  btn.onclick = openTab(event, 'NewTabEvent');
  document.getElementByClassName("tab").appendChild(btn);

  //add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
  const currentDiv = document.getElementById("addnewtab");
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
}

function openTab(evt, tabName) {

var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}

tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");

for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
}

document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

}
```

```css
#createNewTab {
  margin-bottom: 8.09px;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-182.9deg, rgb(20, 90, 241) 50%, rgb(5, 105, 256) 50%);
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 4px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  border-color: rgb(20, 90, 241);
}
```

```html
<!-- creates the tabs -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'FirstTab')">First Tab</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="addTab()">+</button>
</div>

<div id="FirstTab" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>This is the first tab</h3>
  <p>this inside part shouldnt be too bad... right?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you pressed F12 to open your developer tools and looked at the Console tab? This is where you will see errors, like the one we see right here when we run this code `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"`. This means that somewhere on a line where you are trying to access the `style` property of something, that something is `null` and not the object you thought it was. Your console will give you the exactly line number.

Comment: You pass the string `NewTabEvent`, to `openTab` which then tries to find an element with the id `NewTabEvent`, but there isn't one.  Why do you think that `document.getElementById(tabName)` should be able to locate an element with id `NewTabEvent`?  You also look for an element with id `addnewtab` but that doesn't exist either.

Comment: Thanks yall. the line thats having the issue is "document.getElementById(tabName).style.display... in thte javascript openTab function. I can't figure out what is wrong with this. I am sure its the "tabname" variable being passed as a parameter, but I can't figure out how I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

in the Run Code Snippet I am seeing the following error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null". I recommend you try for..of to loop through getElementsByClassName.

Example:

```
let tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");

for (let tab of tabcontent) {
    tab.style.display = "none";
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: I'm curious, what is the purpose of the loop? I didn't know the getElementsByClassName was something you could loop through. Is it looping through all of the available class names to find what I need? What does the tab.style.display = "none" do?